# Can't get Swift protocol to conform - but code looks perfect to me

Tags: swift

The code below looks like it should work. I get an error saying it doesn't conform to the protocol, but it looks to me like it conforms perfectly to the protocol. What am I doing wrong?

The issue is definitely with both properties as I need to comment out both of them (in the protocol) to prevent the error.

```
class MyOtherClass {
}

class AnotherClass {
}

protocol MyProtocol {
  var type: AnyClass { get }
  var myClosure: (text: String) -> MyOtherClass { get }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
  var type = AnotherClass.self
  var myClosure = {
    (text: String) -> MyOtherClass in
    return MyOtherClass()
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: I didn't put this because I thought it was obvious. The exact error message is: "Type 'MyClass' does not conform to protocol 'MyProtocol'".

Comment: You may want to post *all* the error messages (e.g. what I see when I paste your code into a Playground, and show the "Debug Area" window; there's at least five more detailed errors; in a full-blown project they're available in the compiler log.)

Comment: The full error messages can be found in the compiler log in the "Report navigator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is for some reason unable to guess the types of your properties in your class. Specifying types will fix the problem.

```
class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var type : AnyClass = AnotherClass.self
    var myClosure : ((text: String) -> MyOtherClass) = { (text: String) in
        return MyOtherClass()
    }
}
```